# Add className to elements based on received number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do a *7 segment led display*, and based on number that the application receive, it has to add the disable `className` to specific item. I've been thinking in a logic to this, but I don't know how to set it up in the code.

#### Logic:

1. Do a `switch` to get what is the received number.
2. According to the number, I'm doing a `disabledSegments` array. (e.g. `disabledSegments = ['segment-a', 'segment-b', 'segment-c']`).
3. And this is the part that I'm stopped... I coudn't think in a logic to solve my problem.

**App:**

```
function App() {  
  let disabledSegments = [];

  switch(3) {
    case '1':
        disabledSegments = ['segment-a', 'segment-d', 'segment-e', 'segment-f', 'segment-g']
        break;
    case '2':
        disabledSegments = ['segment-c', 'segment-f'];
        break;
    case '3':
        disabledSegments = ['segment-e', 'segment-f'];
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }

  return(
    <div className="led-number">
      <div className="segment segment-a">
        <svg width="69" height="15" viewBox="0 0 69 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M14.269 14.8295H54.5517L68.4885 1.59469C67.1985 0.597612 65.5846 3.8147e-06 63.8301 3.8147e-06H4.63794C2.89411 3.8147e-06 1.29303 0.589094 0.00726318 1.57233L14.269 14.8295Z" fill="#262A34"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
      
      <div className="segment segment-b">
        <svg width="17" height="65" viewBox="0 0 17 65" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M0.624405 14.2662V55.4704L12.2954 64.2173C14.77 62.9539 16.4669 60.3866 16.4669 57.4177V5.62484C16.4669 3.80751 15.8299 2.14251 14.7721 0.832241L0.624405 14.2662Z" fill="#262A34"/>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div className="segment segment-c">
        <svg width="17" height="65" viewBox="0 0 17 65" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M0.624405 50.7207V9.51645L12.2954 0.769611C14.77 2.03407 16.4669 4.60029 16.4669 7.56917V59.3621C16.4669 61.1783 15.8299 62.8433 14.7721 64.1557L0.624405 50.7207Z" fill="#262A34"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
  
      <div className="segment segment-d">
        <svg width="69" height="15" viewBox="0 0 69 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M14.269 0.169458H54.5517L68.4885 13.4053C67.1985 14.4003 65.5846 15 63.8301 15H4.63793C2.8941 15 1.29302 14.4088 0.00725555 13.4256L14.269 0.169458Z" fill="#262A34"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
      
      <div className="segment segment-e">
        <svg width="16" height="65" viewBox="0 0 16 65" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M1.71614 64.1944C0.644493 62.8799 0 61.2032 0 59.3741V7.58124C0 4.61236 1.69695 2.04614 4.17155 0.781677L15.8425 9.52852V51.064L1.71614 64.1944Z" fill="#262A34"/>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div className="segment segment-f">
        <svg width="16" height="65" viewBox="0 0 16 65" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M1.71614 0.815502C0.644493 2.1311 0 3.80888 0 5.63687V57.4298C0 60.3986 1.69695 62.9659 4.17155 64.2293L15.8425 55.4825V13.947L1.71614 0.815502Z" fill="#262A34"/>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div className="segment segment-g">
        <svg width="63" height="17" viewBox="0 0 63 17" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M51.4494 0.390018H11.0175L0.249847 8.32726L11.0175 16.2656H26.4329H36.034H51.4494L62.217 8.32726L51.4494 0.390018Z" fill="#262A34"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.led-number {
    position: relative;
    width: 75px;
    height: 135px;
    margin: 0px 5px; }

.segment {position: absolute}

.segment-a {    
    left: 3px;
    top: 0; }

.segment-b {    
    right: 0;
    top: 2px; }

.segment-c {
    right: 0;
    bottom: -1px; }

.segment-d {
    left: 3px;
    bottom: -3px; }

.segment-e {
    left: 0;
    bottom: -1px; }

.segment-f {
    left: 0;
    top: 2px; }

.segment-g {
    left: 6px;
    top: 58px; }

.segment-disable svg path {fill: #DDDDDD !important;}
```

Output without logic / Expected output:

[image: OutputWithoutLogic]
[image: ExpectedOutput]

P.S: The number in the `switch` is hard coded just to show the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know about the disabled segments by adding them in the `disabledSegments` array.

So, you need to check for disabled elements and pass them disabled `className`. there are many ways to do that. as a solution, you can check every segment too if they are in the `disabledSemgents` and add the `segment-disable` class name for the disabled item:

```
<div className={`segment segment-a ${disabledSegments.includes("seggment-a") && "segment-disable" }`}>
  <svg width="69" height="15" viewBox="0 0 69 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M14.269 14.8295H54.5517L68.4885 1.59469C67.1985 0.597612 65.5846 3.8147e-06 63.8301 3.8147e-06H4.63794C2.89411 3.8147e-06 1.29303 0.589094 0.00726318 1.57233L14.269 14.8295Z" fill="#262A34"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

since the logic is the same for the other segments, you can create a simple function to do that:

```
function disableCheker (segmenetName) {
  let className = "segment" + segmenetName
  if (disabledSegments.includes(segmentName)) {
    className += "segment-disable"
  }
  
  return className;
}
```

With this simple implementation, the `segment` class name and the segmanet name are always passed to the `className`, but if the `segmentName` was in the `disabledSegments` array, the `segment-disable` class name also added to the other classNames and return them as a string, so easy you can use this function to determines your className in segments elements:

```
<div className={disbaleChecker("segment-a")}>
 // rest of the codes ...
</div>

<div className={disbaleChecker("segment-b")}>
 // rest of the codes ...
</div>
```

But, wait a minute, with this approach, your segments will not re-render with changes on the `disabledSegments` array.
So, easily you can create a state variable instead of defining your `disablesSegments` array in the component.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function App () {
  const [disabledSegments, setDisabledSegments] = useState([])

  // rest of the codes ...
  
  handleChange = () => {
    switch(numer) {
      case '1':
        setDisabledSegments(['segment-a', 'segment-d', 'segment-e', 'segment-f', 'segment-g'])
        break;
      case '2':
        setDisabledSegments(['segment-c', 'segment-f']);
        break;
      case '3':
        setDisabledSegments(['segment-e', 'segment-f']);
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }
  }

  // rest of the codes ...
}
```